# XSRF check failed in angular after post to jira

Tags: angular

I have an issue with post request when I want to add a new member to JIRA.
For Firefox and Internet Explorer everything working perfectly. Only for chrome, I am still getting XSRF check failed which I can not solve. Please help.

This is my header `chromehttpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            Authorization: JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('pttk-user')).token,
            'X-Atlassian-Token': 'nocheck',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'Set-Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=A193DF912718D7B98CAAA1344EA34FC3; Path=/; HttpOnly'
        }),
        withCredentials: true
    }`

Answer (score 0):

remove the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' header from the client and also do you really need x-requested-with etc. probably you also need to set an origin. first try without.

```
chromehttpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Authorization': JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('pttk-user')).token,
                'Origin', "http(s)://server:port/"
                'X-Atlassian-Token': 'nocheck',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                'Set-Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=A193DF912718D7B98CAAA1344EA34FC3; Path=/; HttpOnly'
            }),
            withCredentials: true
        }
```

Comment: some additional reference: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Jira-7-rest-api-XSRF-check-failed-for-post-issue-with/qaq-p/488706

Answer (score 0):

For chrome you need to Override the user agent string.

Steps to override in chrome temporarily

1. Press Command+Shift+P (Mac) or Control+Shift+P (Windows, Linux, ChromeOS) to open the Command Menu.
2. Type network conditions, select Show Network conditions, and press Enter to open the Network conditions tab.
3. In the User agent section disable the Select automatically checkbox.
4. Select a user agent string from the list, or enter your own custom string.